how to prevent alt+arrows from moving cursor to end/begin of a word
In emacs I mapped alt+<arrows> to switch windows but on macOS terminal it instead moves cursor to begin/end of a word. How to prevent this?

You can do it in terminal Settings under Profiles -> Keyboard.
Just remove those two shortcuts. Alt + arrows correspond to \033f and \033b.


yes i deleted them but still its the same behaviour

btw i'm using logitech mx key keyboard and mapped alt to cmd and vice versa

Key map swap should not matter, I've also swapped CMD/Option. Are you sure you've removed those keyboard shortcuts under your current Profile (Default)?

yes i removed all the alt+arrows

i checked again, there are no alt+arrows under Pro(default) profile and alt+arrows still not switching windows in emacs(I've mapped)
